# How to disable resizing split view items in NSSplitViewController

Tags: macos, nssplitviewcontroller

I have a split view controller. I made everything working but one thing:

The user is able to drag the center bar to adjust the size of the bottom view.

I have been fiddling with the storyboard for a while but did not find a way to disable this.

[image: normal split view]

[image: bottom down]

[image: bottom up]

Is there a way to prevent it from moving like the picture above? Thanks.

Comment: did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

Your images are broken but here's my guess what you need

```
override func splitView(_ splitView: NSSplitView, effectiveRect proposedEffectiveRect: NSRect, forDrawnRect drawnRect: NSRect, ofDividerAt dividerIndex: Int) -> NSRect {
    return NSZeroRect
}
```